# Scipy Stats ttest_1samp Hypothesis Testing For Comparing Previous Performance To Sample

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

**My Problem I'm Trying To Solve**

I have 11 months worth of performance data:

```
        Month  Branded  Non-Branded  Shopping  Grand Total
0    2/1/2015     1330          334       161         1825
1    3/1/2015     1344          293       197         1834
2    4/1/2015      899          181       190         1270
3    5/1/2015      939          208       154         1301
4    6/1/2015     1119          238       179         1536
5    7/1/2015      859          238       170         1267
6    8/1/2015      996          340       183         1519
7    9/1/2015     1138          381       172         1691
8   10/1/2015     1093          395       176         1664
9   11/1/2015     1491          426       199         2116
10  12/1/2015     1539          530       156         2225
```

Let's say it's February, 1 2016 and I'm asking "are the results in January statistically different from the past 11 months?"

```
       Month  Branded  Non-Branded  Shopping  Grand Total
11  1/1/2016     1064          408       106         1578
```

**I came across a blog...**

I came across [iaingallagher](http://iaingallagher.tumblr.com/post/50980987285/t-tests-in-python)'s blog. I will reproduce here (in case the blog goes down).

> **1-sample t-test**
>
> The 1-sample t-test is used when we want to compare a sample mean to a
>   population mean (which we already know). The average British man is
>   175.3 cm tall. A survey recorded the heights of 10 UK men and we want to know whether the mean of the sample is different from the
>   population mean.

```
# 1-sample t-test
from scipy import stats
one_sample_data = [177.3, 182.7, 169.6, 176.3, 180.3, 179.4, 178.5, 177.2, 181.8, 176.5]

one_sample = stats.ttest_1samp(one_sample_data, 175.3)

print "The t-statistic is %.3f and the p-value is %.3f." % one_sample
```

Result:

```
The t-statistic is 2.296 and the p-value is 0.047.
```

**Finally, to my question...**

In iaingallagher's example, he knows the population mean and is comparing a sample (`one_sample_data`).  In MY example, I want to see if `1/1/2016` is statistically different from the previous 11 months.  So in my case, the previous 11 months is an array (instead of a single population mean value) and my sample is one data point (instead of an array)... so it's kind of backwards.

**QUESTION**

If I was focused on the `Shopping` column data:

Will `scipy.stats.`[ttest_1samp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html)`([161,197,190,154,179,170,183,172,176,199,156], 106)` produce a valid result even though my sample (first parameters) is a list of previous results and I'm comparing it to a `popmean` that's not the population mean but instead one sample.

If this is not the correct stats function, any recommendation on what to use for this hypothesis test situation?

Comment: This is more of a stats question than a programming question.  You would likely be better off removing the programming aspects and just ask about the stats on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I already did that before posting the question here (even did a bounty on the question) but not sure my conclusion that I can use `ttest_1samp` is true. Even with a bounty on cross validated I didn't get much of a response to this question (which seems like it would be a pretty common one IMO) [Question can be found here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198825/compare-previous-month-to-all-other-previous-months-performance)

Comment: What exactly are you asking here that is not answered there?  That answer is telling you to use a two-sample t-test.  I'm not sure I agree with that, but either way it's still a question for Cross Validated.  Your question there doesn't mention the one-sample t-test, so the answer doesn't address it.  If you have a question about the statistical validity of the one-sample t-test for this use case, you should ask about the one-sample t-test on Cross Validated.

Comment: I don't agree with you.  This question is a programming-specific question regarding a function in `scipy` and whether or not the first argument can be swapped with an array where that array is the historic data instead of the sample data, and instead of inputting a population mean, I'm inputting a single sample.  The question is, if this will still return a valid comparison.  There is a lot of scipy users on here that might know the answer to this.  The user that gave the answer on cross validation used R and I'm trying to find an equivalent to that and not sure if `ttest_1samp` is that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the `"Shopping"` column, try to create a .xlsx or .csv file containing the data from only the `"Shopping"`column.

This way you could import this data and make use of pandas to perform the same T-test for each column individually.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
data = pd.read_excel("datafile.xlxs")
    one_sample_data = data["Shopping"]

    one_sample = stats.ttest_1samp(one_sample_data, 175.3)
```

Comment: theres no need to create a new dataframe. just take the original dataframe, lets call it "df"  and pick out the Shopping column with df["Shopping"].  Then you can do stats.ttest_1samp(df["Shopping"], 175.3)